# WordPress and Nginx +certbob SSL Redirection Issue on admin pages only (ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

Tags: wordpress, docker, nginx, ssl, https

I'm facing an issue with SSL redirection on my WordPress site hosted with Nginx. When attempting to access /wp-admin/, I encounter an "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" error. The site itself loads correctly with the domain smartdomaine.app.

I defined the virtualhost in a nginx config file for nginx docker container( ./data/nginx/app.config)

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name smartdomaine.app;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name smartdomaine.app;
    server_tokens off;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/smartdomaine.app/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/smartdomaine.app/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge/ {
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://wordpress:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

My wp-config.php contains :

```
define('WP_HOME', 'https://smartdomaine.app');
define('WP_SITEURL', 'https://smartdomaine.app');
...
define('FORCE_SSL_ADMIN', true);
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO'], 'https') !== false) {
        $_SERVER['HTTPS'] = 'on';
}
```

Site loads correctly with smartdomaine.app but I have ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS  on smartdomaine.app/wp-admin

My docker-compose :

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:1.15-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    command: "/bin/sh -c 'while :; do sleep 6h & wait $${!}; nginx -s reload; done & nginx -g \"daemon off;\"'"
  certbot:
    image: certbot/certbot
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    entrypoint: "/bin/sh -c 'trap exit TERM; while :; do certbot renew; sleep 12h & wait $${!}; done;'"
  wordpress:
    image: wordpress
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 8081:80
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX: ${WORDPRESS_TABLE_PREFIX}
    volumes:
      - wordpress:/var/www/html
  db:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${MYSQL_DATABASE}
      MYSQL_USER: ${MYSQL_USER}
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: ${MYSQL_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/mysql
volumes:
  wordpress:
  db:
```

I'm seeking assistance to identify and resolve the SSL redirection issue causing "ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS" on accessing /wp-admin/. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!